# Windows Error dialog - 'Errors occurred' - Where is this coming from?

Tags: python, windows, error-handling, wxpython

I am dealing with a legacy Python application which uses WxPython, InnoSetup and py2exe and has a custom sys.excepthook that should deal with all exceptions. Yet, when an exception occurs, after the custom exception handler has finished and the main window is closed, this dailog pops up. The worst part is that it points to a non-existant log file, confusing users. The dialog reads 'Errors occurred - See the logfile ... for details."

Where could this dialog be coming from? Is this some sort of system default?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See the logfile ... for details.

Comment: Are you sure it does not exist? The log file's name seems odd since it is a `.exe.log`. Perhaps it only shows up as `some_filename.exe` as windows' default configuration hides known file extensions.

Comment: @Wombatz, at least in the given location that file does not exist.

Comment: Perhaps whatever writes that log file has no permission to do so. Could you change the permissions to allow writing to that directory?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is due to different effects.

py2exe by default redirects Stderr to a logfile named `sys.executable + '.log'` and generates that dialog.

When permissions do not allow to write to that folder, it is instead redirected to `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\...`. There, that file actually exists and may give hints to the cause of the crash.

The last finding I made was that the custom exception handler was activated way too late. During imports and inits, the program had plenty of opportunity to crash before the custom handler kicked in.

Some more info on: [py2exe error handling redirection and popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835641/py2exe-error-handling-redirection-and-popup)